# SelectionMode multiple does not work with checkbox

Tags: ajax, checkbox, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to select a row if clicks on a checkbox & if i click on checkbox it should select the row. 
There should be multiple selection with checkboxes & rows as well.
Primefaces: 3.3 
JSF: 2.1

```
<p:dataTable id="csrTable" var="assignedTask"
                                    value="#{worklistPage.assignedTasksList}" paginator="true"
                                    paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="25" rowKey="#{assignedTask.id}"
                                    selection="#{worklistPage.selectedTasks}"
                                    selectionMode="multiple"
                                    styleClass="selectedRow" border="0">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{worklistPage.onRowSelect}" update=":form1" />
     <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
```

Comment: And what **is** the **actual** behaviour?

Comment: @Why you added  `selectionMode="multiple"` multiple places.

Comment: I want to have both the funcationalities, row click selection n check box selection at the same time. Row selection can be achived by add selectionMode in dataTable and column selection mode adds the check boxes

Comment: Ok So Not working means ? What issue you are getting ?

Comment: If i remove selectionMode="multiple" from datatable component then i can only select the row when i click on checkbox. I want that row can be selected either with checkbox or by clicking on the row.

Comment: This requested feature is implemented in a newer PF release. So either upgrade or try to backport the code yourself

Comment: I have upgraded to primefaces 5.0 let's hope it will work.:)